# Iframe video 100% width

Tags: css, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I am trying to get a YouTube video to display at 100% width and height. It seems the iframe itself is doing what I want, however, once the video plays it is only 100% width up to 1100px.

I have tried searching the web but cannot find a solution to get the video itself to be the same width as the video poster and iframe width.

Comment: Unfortunately the link in this question is now 404 (I think the domain expired?) so there is not much of a question left. This is why it is very worthwhile getting all code/logs/info into the question itself. [Read more here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/472495).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZLyS2wHiZM8" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class="video"></iframe>
</div>
```

[Reference article](https://www.h3xed.com/web-development/how-to-make-a-responsive-100-width-youtube-iframe-embed)

Answer (score 2):

I assume your video ratio is 16:9. Maybe you can try this:

```
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 56.25vw;
}
.video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

This is an example [link](http://video-d69d2e.webflow.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Your video has already a 100% width. When I make a right-click on the left or right side of the video, the context menu of the youtube video appears. [Check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEDlO.jpg)

I think the problem is about your video. Your video don't have the right width and height to appear correctly.